# SpringBoot @RequestBody pojo not mapping to my json

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Can anyone help me fix this. I have hard coded json object which is suppposed to map to my POJO but I'm getting null values in my Spring Controller. I've checked my getters and setters. They seems to be correct. What am i doing wrong here ?

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/dashboard")
public Dashboard getDashboard(@RequestBody PaginationRequest paginationRequest) {
      return topcatService.getDashboard(paginationRequest);
}
```

json

```
 var paginationRequest = { grouping  : e.target.value ,total : "1", currentPage : "1", pageSize : "5"};
```

POJO

```
 public class PaginationRequest {
        private String grouping;
        private String total;
        private String  currentPage;
        private String pageSize;

       //setter/getter
    }
```

Comment: you should tell us whats not working.

Comment: PaginationRequest has null values. json is not mapping correctly to the POJO

Answer (score 3):

Make properties public and annotate each property with @JsonProperty() (i.e. @JsonProperty("grouping") ), for example. It's likely your getters and setters don't follow standard naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have to create a valid json first and test if you data comes correctly to your controller.

Just try to send an example json like that:

```
var paginationRequest = '{\"grouping\":\"anyValue\",\"total\":\"1\",\"currentPage\":\"1\",\"pageSize\": \"5\"}';
```

this means you send only a String in a json format.

If you have an Object you maybe have to convert your Object to a json String:

```
var somejson =  JSON.stringify(someobject);
```

Comment: tried this
var paginationRequest = '{\"grouping\":\"anyValue\",\"total\":\"1\",\"currentPage\":\"1\",\"pageSize\": \"5\"}'

but doesn't seem to work

Comment: then you have to provide more information about what you are doing, how you send the json and so on.

Comment: I'm trying to pass hardcoded json which is paginationRequest (provided in the original code) which should be converted into POJO PaginationRequest.java.

Comment: this I already know, but you have to update your question and provide more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think i know whats the problem

And its the dumbest thing that i did.

Check where is your `@RequiredBody` annotation comes from. I mistakenly imported it from swagger dependency whilst it should be from spring. They are identical in signature hence i couldnt figure out the source

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to suggest some small changes,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Dashboard getDashboard(@RequestBody PaginationRequest paginationRequest) {
```

Comment: tried it just now. Still getting the same null values.

Comment: Was there any solution to this ?